# Test automation and verification for reports in web applications

Tags: java, testing, report

I am testing a java web application where in admins can run various custom reports.
The UI for reports lets admin enter various attribute values for pre defined attributes like date time filter, countries list for which admin wants to run report, and some other pre defined attributes. What is the best way to automate verification of data thats shown in reports. I want to check that this data is correct when compared with DB

Thanks
Vishal

Answer (score 0):

If 
1. the reports are rendered in web/html, and 
2. what you are trying to achieve is verify the UI output against the database and 
3. you are willing and allowed to invest significant amount of resources/time on achieving this kind of verification, 
I would recommend using [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) with [JUnit](http://junit.org/). There are likely issues beyond what methods you adopt, but this is one of those things that you can begin with.